# number_format every second number a img

Tags: php, html, numbers, currency

I try to make a virutal money system and dont get the "number_format"
I want it like the number "7951753" and want that output:
795 17 53

Other example:
$money = 10001;
1 0 1

How I can make that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

```
$mynumber=7951753;
echo substr($mynumber, 0, 3)." Gold ". substr($mynumber, 3, 2)." Silver " . substr($mynumber, 5, 2)." Bronze ";
```

above code produces output:-

> 795 Gold 17 Silver 53 Bronze

You may do same with 10001 to get 1 Gold 0 Silver 1 Bronze :)

Have a try!

Comment: That worked, thanks but if I do 10001it will be 1 Gold 00 Silver 01 Bronze, how I remove the 0?

Comment: Try, 
You dont need to remove! instead choose right one ;) 
$mynumber=10001;
echo substr($mynumber, 0, 1)." Gold ". substr($mynumber, 1, 1). " Silver". substr($mynumber, 4, 4)." Bronze ";

Comment: Perfect! Thank you a lot *-*

Comment: Great! you can do it with any combination! haha now up-vote ? lol :)

Comment: I try to. It said "Thanks for the feedback! Once you earn a total of 15 reputation, your votes will change the pubblicly displayed post score.

And got a problem with that:
$mynumber=1;
Output: 1 Gold
But if its 1, it must be 1 bronze

Comment: I was just kidding your issue has resolved i am glad please do come back if any issues further. thanks.

Comment: Ah ok.
As I said:
$mynumber=1; Output: 1 Gold But if its 1, it must be 1 bronze

Comment: If you put a low number in, than you will get gold not bronze.

Comment: You need to code for that! where is your code ? & where do you stuck! ?

Comment: $mynumber=73;
echo substr($mynumber, 0, 1)."</font><img src='../img/gold.png'> <font color='#b0b1b3'>". substr($mynumber, 1, 1). "</font><img src='../img/silber.png'> <font color='#d35e32'>". substr($mynumber, 4, 4)."</font></b><img src='../img/kupfer.png'> ";

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, display fail on posting that here:

```
Number: 7951753
```

Output: 795 Gold 17 Silver 53 Bronze

Other example:

```
Number: 10001
```

Output: 1 Gold 0 Silver 1 Bronze

Comment: Please remove your edit of question from here and edit as a question itself thanks!